# Are Positive Linear Functionals Scalar Multiples of States?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

My tutor recently remarked that one can reduce most problems concerning positive linear functionals to just considering states, since any positive linear functional $\omega$ on a $C^*$-Algebra $A$ is just a scalar multiple of some state on $A$.

Is this true? How does one see this, is it trivial?

Comment: Yes, it is trivial. If $\omega$ is a non-zero positive functional on $A$, then $\omega/\|\omega\|$ is a state on $A$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Ah of course, thank you. Sometimes you overlook the easiest things...

Comment: Glad to help. Don't worry about it, happens to everyone.